# Cypress Vue component test crashes on import Ref type (does not provide an export named 'Ref')

Tags: typescript, vue.js, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I wrote a Cypress component test that simply mounts my component and asserts it exists. The component itself imports Vue's Ref type and is also defined as a TypeScript component.

When running the test, Cypress crashes on the following error:

> The requested module '/__cypress/src/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue.js?v=861dc0d7' does not provide an export named 'Ref'

I've already updated my Cypress `tsconfig.json`'s "`types`" with vue, but haven't found any further direction on how to solve this issue.

```
tsconfig.json
---
{

  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "types": ["cypress", "vue", "node"],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "allowJs": true,
    "paths": {
      "~": ["."]
    },
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.js"]
}
```

My Cypress config:

```
cypress.config.js
---
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress")

module.exports = defineConfig({
    component: {
        supportFile: "cypress/support/component.ts",
        devServer: {
            framework: "vue",
            bundler: "vite",
        },
    },
})
```

This is how my component is written:

```
MyComponent.vue
---
<template>
    <div class="my-component">
        {{ counter }}
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import type { Ref } from "vue"

const counter: Ref<number> = ref(1)
</script>
```

And the test goes as following:

```
MyComponent.cy.ts
---
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent.vue"

beforeEach(() => {
    cy.mount(MyComponent)
})

it("Test My Component", () => {
    cy.get(".my-component").should("exist")
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the origin of the issue. It seems that in my `tsconfig.json` file, I was extending from nuxt' tsconfig (`"extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json"`)

It seems that simply removing this line solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have `cypress.config.js` in a Typescript project, which makes me think that file is indicating to Cypress not to use Typescript (`import type {Ref}` is not valid syntax in javascript).

If I use your component in a running Typescript project that has `cypress.config.ts` and the corresponding changes, it recognizes that type import.

(Note I have older version of Vue)

```js
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
  component: {
    devServer: {
      framework: "vue-cli",
      bundler: "webpack",
    },
  },
})
```

You also need an import for concrete `ref` in the component

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import type { Ref } from "vue"
import { ref } from "vue"            <-- add this 

const counter: Ref<number> = ref(1) 
</script>
```

Comment: I transformed Cypress config to a .ts file, but that doesn't solve the problem either. In my example, I was indeed missing importing the ref. I feel like I'm missing something else though.